# Unable to push local changes live using Git Push Heroku Master

Tags: django, git, heroku, github

I'm new to GitHub and have gotten myself into a tangle. I've been successfully deploying code to a Heroku / Django app. However, my last commit was unsuccessful. This is my flow...

```
- Git add .
- Git commit -m "social media icons"
- Git push heroku master
```

The last command returns....

```
Fetching repository, done.
Everything up-to-date
```

Everything is not up to date. One thing I've discovered on my GitHub app is that I have 2 branches "production" and "master". Master was last updated Sept 8th. I've run a few commands including "git pull origin master" and "git push -f" based on other Stack answers. The latter did seem to push something but not the changes in local. Sorry, I'm trying to find my feet here!

Comment: which branch are you on? do a `git status` to see where you are since you are pushing to master.

Comment: @tayfun it says I'm on "branch production"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on production branch then you will need to do

```
git push heroku production:master
```

Heroku will only deploy the master branch so this command is you pushing your local production branch into the master branch on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

So you are on branch production but your other branch master is up to date. If you want to push the current branch you are on, you should explicitly say so:  `git push heroku production`.

I would highly advise you to [try git](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1), it's an excellent resource.